# Authentication failed: TImeout for cockpit access in CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, authentication, cockpit

## PROBLEM

When I try to login to `cockpit` on **CentOS 7** using URL `https://localhost:9090` using the `root` credentials, I get **Authentication failed: Timeout** error. Have searched the web for solution but not able to troubleshoot the problem.

## STEPS USED TO INSTALL COCKPIT

```
# yum install cockpit cockpit-dashboard
# systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=cockpit
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

## OUTPUTS

### firewall-cmd --list-all

```
target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: em1
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client nfs rpc-bind ssh
  ports: 5901/tcp 944/tcp 944/udp 945/tcp 945/udp 946/udp 9090/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

### /var/log/message output

```
Mar  1 23:22:20 srv01 systemd: Starting Cockpit Web Service...
Mar  1 23:22:20 srv01 systemd: Started Cockpit Web Service.
Mar  1 23:22:20 srv01 cockpit-ws: Using certificate: /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed.cert
Mar  1 23:22:40 srv01 cockpit-session: pam_ssh_add: Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
Mar  1 23:22:40 srv01 systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
Mar  1 23:22:40 srv01 systemd-logind: New session 6 of user root.
Mar  1 23:22:40 srv01 systemd: Started Session 6 of user root.
Mar  1 23:22:41 srv01 journal: clutter_actor_set_size: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Mar  1 23:22:41 srv01 journal: clutter_actor_show: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Mar  1 23:23:10 srv01 cockpit-ws: cockpit-session: session timed out during authentication
Mar  1 23:23:10 srv01 org.gtk.vfs.Daemon: A connection to the bus can't be made
Mar  1 23:23:10 srv01 cockpit-ws: cockpit-session: authentication timed out
Mar  1 23:23:10 srv01 systemd-logind: Removed session 6.
Mar  1 23:23:10 srv01 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Mar  1 23:23:11 srv01 journal: clutter_actor_set_size: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Mar  1 23:23:11 srv01 journal: clutter_actor_show: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
```

### journalctl -f output

```
Mar 01 23:22:20 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in systemd[1]: Starting Cockpit Web Service...
Mar 01 23:22:20 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in systemd[1]: Started Cockpit Web Service.
Mar 01 23:22:20 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in cockpit-ws[6374]: Using certificate: /etc/cockpit/ws-certs.d/0-self-signed.cert
Mar 01 23:22:21 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in rtkit-daemon[1123]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Mar 01 23:22:21 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in rtkit-daemon[1123]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Mar 01 23:22:40 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in cockpit-session[6430]: pam_ssh_add: Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
Mar 01 23:22:40 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of root.
Mar 01 23:22:40 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in systemd-logind[1129]: New session 6 of user root.
Mar 01 23:22:40 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in systemd[1]: Started Session 6 of user root.
Mar 01 23:22:40 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in cockpit-session[6430]: pam_unix(cockpit:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 01 23:22:41 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in gnome-shell[2736]: clutter_actor_set_size: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Mar 01 23:22:41 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in gnome-shell[2736]: clutter_actor_show: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Mar 01 23:23:10 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in cockpit-ws[6374]: cockpit-session: session timed out during authentication
Mar 01 23:23:10 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[6465]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Mar 01 23:23:10 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in cockpit-session[6430]: pam_unix(cockpit:session): session closed for user root
Mar 01 23:23:10 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in cockpit-ws[6374]: cockpit-session: authentication timed out
Mar 01 23:23:10 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in systemd-logind[1129]: Removed session 6.
Mar 01 23:23:10 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
Mar 01 23:23:11 srv01.vlsi.silicon.ac.in gnome-shell[2736]: clutter_actor_set_size: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
```

[Cockpit Login using Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0u5i.png)

[Cockpit login failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08RiK.png)

Comment: Please share photos where and how do you get this error.

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Comment: When trying to connect to cockpit using the URL https://localhost:9090 using root credentials, I monitor /var/log/messages and also journalctl -f  which I have pasted in the original post. I have also added the two screenshots when I login and when it fails. Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, there are multiple factors that can be the reason for this. 1. use another account instead of root, because root is blocked from sshd and some other places. 2. what is your routero or type of network that you use, because "timeout" means the connection can not be established. 3. from which device you are trying to connect and what is the connection between them 4. try to not use localhost but the ip on the adapter which service listens.

Comment: 1. When I use any other valid user, it gives an error that "wrong username or password"  2. The server is on a local VLAN network on a L2/L3 switch.  3. I have logged into the server using tightVNC and run Firefox on the server itself.  4. I tried using the IP address as well and it's the same error.  I am not sure if that helps. Not sure how to debug this problem.

Comment: Try to allow root user to login in this file ```/etc/ssh/sshd_config```

Comment: I set `PermitRootLogin yes` in  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and still the same error!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the Origins and you need to specify them like this in the conf file

```
[WebService]  
Origins = http://10.0.0.18 http://192.168.1.0 
AllowUnencrypted = yes
```